# Prolog - How to generate a number with certain prerequisites?

Tags: list, random, prolog, numbers

So I want to create a simple number generator that generates a number between 1 and 9, but it is not allowed to be part of three lists provided (lists of numbers). An example:

```
findnumber(Number, [1,2,3], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]).
Number = 9.
```

or:

```
findnumber(Number, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]).
Number = 7;
Number = 8;
Number = 9.
```

How would I go about this, I tried this:

```
findnumber(Number, List1, List2, List3) :-
  random_between(1, 9, Number),
  not(member(Number, List1)),
  not(member(Number, List2)),
  not(member(Number, List3)).
```

I thought this would work but apparently not, I think it is because the Number is generated beforehand so it can't really find the prerequisites. It merely checks if they aren't members and if they are, then the predicate fails.

Hopefully someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works fine for me...How do you test it ??

Comment: When I run it, it fails. But whilst I was typing this up I tried something and now it works, not sure if I should give the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, there have been several exercises under this general theme. The tasks force you to hack together programs that run counter to elementary properties of logical relations: In particular, we expect logical relations to *not depend on implicit global states*, such as the state of a random number generator. These are examples of logic *hacking*, not of logic *programming*.

In any case, your solution and also analysis are perfectly valid.

One easy way out is to simply **repeatedly try** to generate such integers *until you at last succeed*. Prolog makes it easy to repeatedly try, via its built-in backtracking mechanism.

You can use the predicate `repeat/0`, which *succeeds an arbitrary number of times*. So, your query works exactly as expected if you simply prepend a call of `repeat/0`:

```
?- repeat, findnumber(Number, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]).
Number = 9 ;
Number = 9 ;
Number = 8 ;
Number = 8 ;
Number = 7 .
```

You can commit to the *first* solution by wrapping the whole query in `once/1`, i.e.:

```
?- once((repeat, findnumber(Number, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))).
Number = 7.
```

As I said, the whole relation violates elementary properties we expect from a logic program. For example, when posting the exact same query again, I get a **different answer**:

```
?- once((repeat, findnumber(Number, [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]))).
Number = 8.
```

This explains why it "worked" (by coincidence) for one of the commenters.

Such impurities make declarative debugging and many other benefits of logic programming inapplicable. I recommend you choose a different instructor. See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) to learn more about properties we expect from logical relations, and how you can benefit from them in your work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what exactly is wrong with the exercise if seen as an introductory exercise. I recently started prolog and I think that it is a pretty good attempt at teaching me how to code in prolog for the time being. What kind of introductory exercise would you recommend to teach if seen from a logically pure perspective?

Comment: When you query a Prolog predicate, and ask: Which solutions are there? Then, when it reports a solution, you expect that the predicate also **holds** for that concrete solution. In other words, when you query `?- p(X).`, and Prolog answers with some binding for `X`, say: `X = t`. Then, you of course expect that `?- p(t).` *also* holds, right? In your exercise, this is not the case, because the predicate also depends on some implicit state of the random number generator, and that changes between invocations! To  solve this in a pure way, make the state of the random number generator explicit!

Answer (score 1):

You can use constraint logic programming (CLP) to easily solve tasks of this kind. For example, with Swi-Prolog you can use following code to define *findnumber*:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

findnumber(Number, List1, List2, List3) :-
    append([List1, List2, List3], NotIn),
    Number in 1..9,
    maplist(#\=(Number), NotIn),
    indomain(Number).
```